# How to find files in my current view that are on a specific branch?

Tags: version-control, clearcase, cleartool

Let's say I have two files: `File1` and `File2`

In the version tree diagram below the `*` indicates the version of my **working copy** selected by my config spec.

Version Trees:

File1 has development on `Branch2` but is now merged to branch `main`

```
| main |
   |
  (0)----| Branch2 |
   |          |
   |         (0)
   |          |
  (1)*<------(1)
```

File2 is on `Branch2` with multiple revisions

```
| main |
   |
  (0)----| Branch2 |
              |
             (0)
              |
             (1)
              |
             (2)*
```

Config Spec:

```
#Pick up Branch2 LATEST unless it has an outgoing merge hyperlink type
element * {version(.../Branch2/LATEST)&&!hltype(Merge,->)}    
element * /main/LATEST
```

What I'd like to be able to do is find only the files that are on `Branch2` that I'm currently looking at.

I've tried this:

```
cleartool find . -cview -type f -version "brtype(Branch2)" -print
```

It returns every version of every file that is on `Branch2`

```
.\File1@@\main\Branch2\0
.\File1@@\main\Branch2\1
.\File2@@\main\Branch2\0
.\File2@@\main\Branch2\1
.\File2@@\main\Branch2\2
```

I'd like only

```
.\File2@@\main\Branch2\2
```

What is the `cleartool find` command(s) that will return only `File2`, the working copy version as a results?  I'd prefer a one line command versus a multiple step process.

**To Clarify**

I only want listed files that are on `Branch2` **and** selected as my working copy according to my config spec.  `.\File2@@\main\Branch2\2` is on `Branch2` and is selected as my working copy.  `.\File1@@\main\1` is selected as my working copy, which isn't on `Branch2` and shouldn't be listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be wrong to query for a specific version like "`LATEST`" for files in a branch, because there is no guaranty your config spec actually select the LATEST of a given branch.

The correct way is to [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) *elements*:

- in the current view (`cview`)
- which have a version in that branch (`brtype`)

That means:

```
cd /path/to/your/view/yourVob
cleartool find . -cview -type f -ele "brtype(Branch2)" -print
```

That would still give you `File1`, but that would give it as the version in `/main` only (not `Branch2`)

You can then filter out easily what you need:

```
cleartool find . -cview -type f -ele "brtype(Branch2)" -print | grep Branch2
```

It is still one command, and it doesn't assume you are selecting the `LATEST` of `Branch2`.
If you are selecting any version on `Branch2`, it will be in the result of that find.

Comment: The command is executed on Windows, but I can work with this!

Comment: @jmstoker `grep` is available for Windows with [Gow (Gnu on Windows)](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki): I use `grep` commands in my DOS session every day.

Answer (score -1):

This will get you the latest version on the branch

```
cleartool find . -type f -ele "version(.../Branch2/LATEST)" -print
```

Comment: Your solution still includes a version of `File1` in the list.  I've updated my question to hopefully make it more clear what I'm after.